# Binding a function to this using function.bind

Tags: javascript, function, bind

Don't mind that this is functional programming, what I'm having trouble understanding is what happens when you use a function as first argument in the bind-method?

```
monadWithValue.bind(callback);
```

Usually this is used to assign context by supplying an object that will become what this refers to.

```
var monadWithValue = Monad( value );

function callback(value) {
    var newValue = calculate…new…value…from…value;
    return Monad( newValue );
}

var monadWithNewValue = monadWithValue.bind(callback);
```

Normally I would do something along the lines of this:

```
function add() { 
  return this.a + this.b;
}

var context = {
  a:10,
  b:20
};

add.bind(context);
add();
```

Comment: A function is also just an object...

Comment: Yes, this I understand - but how will it become this? - is newValue then a property of this object? how is the return statement interpreted?

Comment: I'm guessing `monadWithValue.bind` isn't `Function.prototype.bind`, because bind means something special with monads.

Comment: `newValue` has nothing to do with `this`. *Assuming* `monadWithValue` is a function, then `monadWithValue.bind(callback)` makes it so that when you call `monadWithValue()`, `this` inside `monadWithValue` refers to `callback`. That is all. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @deceze - so you agree that monadWithValue.bind isn't Function.prototype.bind in this example?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I don't think it is either, but its quite confusing. But since functions are objects you would actually be able to supply a function as "this" using bind right? are there any use-cases for this?

Comment: I'm *assuming* that it *is*! If it's not, that function could do anything. But it doesn't really matter what it does... `callback` gets passed around as an object and will end up somewhere later on. Maybe as `this` somewhere, or as something else somewhere else. Neither possibility is anything special really.

Comment: Ok, so calling this() - would execute the callback function - I think I get it - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is also just an object...

```
var foo = function () { };
foo.bar = 'baz';
```

You happen to be able to *call* this object with `foo()`, but other than that it behaves exactly the same as any other object. You can bind `this` to `foo` without problems.